# reference vs smart_ptr for dependency inversion

Tags: c++

I have two data types, A and B and I have to store the A instance in B in order to refer the A instance in a B method. Both are instantiated in the main function, so the two variables would live for as long as the program is running.

I don't want to make copies, I want to use something like an old fashioned pointer but also I want to follow (and learn) the modern C++ best practices. So what is the most appropriate type to store the A instance in B? (and why?)

I thought that if I want to use a pointer, the best way with modern C++, is using smart pointers, but references seems easier and lighter, so what is the best practice to refer to a variable created in a scope (for example in the main function) and used in another scope (for example a method of a class that has a pointer to that variable), knowing that the scope where that variable is created lives for as long as the class exists (when the stack is deallocated, it will free both the variable and the object that has the variable reference)?

```
struct A {};

struct B {
 A & a;
 B(A & a) : a(a) {}
};

int main() {
  A a{};
  B b{a};
}
```

or

```
#include<memory>

struct A {};

struct B {
 std::shared_ptr<A> a;
 B(auto a) : a(a) {}
};

int main() {
  B b{std::make_shared<A>()};
}
```

The program I'm making is essentially a bunch of test to learn SDL2, I published the repo here https://github.com/antcolag/prova-sdl, B is the `App` class and A is the `EventHandler` class instantiated inside the main function.

As @πάντα-ῥεῖ noticed in my particular case the only reasonable way is with smart pointer, because I'm trying to use std::thread and std::atomic, but in a most general case what is the best way to replace the old C style pointers, with a more modern approach, when a variable is allocated in the stack, used by some other object and then deallocated from the stack together with the object?

Comment: Would you need to track ownership and references to `A` by many instances of `B`? What is the semantical relationship of these classes?

Comment: Why not just make `A` a member of `B`?

Comment: As they're both going to fall out of scope at the same time, it doesn't matter, but using a shared_ptr in this specific case is awkward. It also depends on who really "owns" the data. If B owns the data, why not just define A as contained by B? That's in effect what your second example is doing, but in a very awkward fashion.

Comment: @Galik I prefer to don't make copies

Comment: There is not enough information here. These decisions are made on the required lifetimes and needed access to the members. You can't make a general rule based on what you have here.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ I'm learning SDL2 making a little game, `A` in my case is the class that handles the std::thread of the event loop, B is a class that stores all the game parts, so it should have a reference to the event handler class too

Comment: @asdru If you need thread safety by default, this is a no brainer: Use a `std::shared_ptr<T>` per `std::thread` instance accessing `T`. Acrtually accessing the data provided by the `T` instabce should be protected additionally against concurrent reading / writing.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the problem, you want to move the instance to a different "owner", with `A a;` it is posible but it requires a `memcpy()` if the scope of the instance is deleted. The most easy solution is to contain it in a shared scope, that is bad because it can be a global scope, the next best thing is to pass the reference to the owner (the structure that contains the data). At the end this are cheap solutions if they are applied over and over, modern c++ has a lot of tools for memory control / flow; most of those are pointer based because the data pointer copy is trivial, note that only in combination with std::atomic or a similar lib is suitable for multithreading.

This example shows how a data pointer can be moved and used without any fancy c++, a small note on the pointer idea, in the example the pointer address is not changing as long as it is not deleted, any reference made will persist even if ref_objs order is changed, the data is "on the wild" and the pointer is a number.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Object {
    int num = 69;
};

struct Container {

    // Better to use std::vector but
    // this shows better what it does
    // Olso can be replaced with 
    // Object * ref_objs [n] if n is fixt
    Object ** ref_objs;
    
    uint32_t n_obj;
    uint32_t n_obj_max;

    void provision_for(uint32_t res_len){
        // To initialize data is better to use
        // use a method insted of the constructor;
        // This alocates n spaces of obj pointers
        ref_objs = new Object * [res_len];
        n_obj_max = res_len;
        n_obj = 0;
    }

    void clear_all(){
        uint32_t i;
        for (i=0; i < n_obj; i++){
            delete ref_objs[i];
        }
        delete [] ref_objs;
        n_obj = 0;
    }

    Object * add_obj(){
        Object * ret = nullptr;
        if (n_obj < n_obj_max){
            ref_objs[n_obj] = new Object;
            ret = ref_objs[n_obj];
            n_obj++;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    void del_obj(uint32_t n){
        if (n < n_obj - 1){
            // keeps them alighned
            ref_objs[n] = ref_objs[n_obj];
        }
        delete ref_objs[n_obj];
        n_obj--;
    }
    int recive_obj(Object * ref){
        int res = 1;
        if (n_obj < n_obj_max){
            ref_objs[n_obj] = ref;
            n_obj++;
            res = 0;
        }
        return res;
    }
    int transfer_to(Container * to, uint32_t item){
        int res = 1;
        if (to->recive_obj(ref_objs[item]) == 0){
            if (item < n_obj - 1){
                ref_objs[item] = ref_objs[n_obj - 1];
            } else {
                ref_objs[item] = nullptr;
            }
            n_obj --;
            res = 0;
        }
        return res;
    }

    Object * at (uint32_t at){
        return ref_objs[at];
    }
    Object & operator [](uint32_t at){
        // [0] is added to asure the compiler that it
        // is a instance and not an array
        return ref_objs[at][0];
    }

};


int main(void){

    Container container_a;
    Container container_b;

    container_a.provision_for(10);
    container_b.provision_for(15);

    Object * x = container_a.add_obj();
    Object * y = container_a.add_obj();
    Object * z = container_b.add_obj();
    std::cout << "container_a len -> " << container_a.n_obj << std::endl;
    std::cout << "container_b len -> " << container_b.n_obj << std::endl;

    y->num = 200;
    container_a.transfer_to(&container_b, 0);
    container_b[1].num = 400;
    std::cout << "container_a obj[0].num -> " << container_a[0].num << std::endl;
    std::cout << "container_b obj[0].num -> " << container_b[0].num << std::endl;
    std::cout << "container_b obj[1].num -> " << container_b.ref_objs[1]->num << std::endl;

    container_a.del_obj(0);
    container_a.clear_all();
    container_b.clear_all();

    return 0;
}
```

(This example is template suitable, just change all `Object` with the typename and the instance will be `Container<Object> container_a;`)

Comment: My question is quite simpler, I was wondering if there was a best practice (choosing between smart pointers and references) to refer to a variable created in a context that remains active for as long as the application is active (for example a variable created in the main function), inside another object that uses that variable

Comment: It will depend mostly on the project use case, i don't like using smart pointer, but that is a preference; use what you like the most, bought make the same work; a good example of "odd - is implementation" is on wxWidgets, each ui element can be created with a new and you never delete them, when they are invoked they are tied to the parent and the main class itself deletes them all. The only "problem" with the references is that you need to track them more, for example when you move then you need to make sure to remove the reference from the origin.